# ХарактЕрный и харАктерный

Tags: омонимы, однокоренные-слова

ХарактЕрный - это значит свойственный чему-то. Например: "На боках у тигра мы можем видеть характерный узор из полосок". ХарАктерным же называют, например, персонажа книги или фильма с ярким характером. Так же еще говорят об актерах, которые играют харАктерные роли, то есть те, где главное - показать натуру и внутренний мир персонажа.
Выходит, что первое слово происходит не от "характера", а от "характеристики", так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ударение в слове - вещь отнюдь не случайная и определяется воздействием различных факторов, в том числе при наличии парных фонетических вариантов может зависеть от смысла слова.

(1) Характер - характеристика, сложный суффикс ИСТИК всегда ударный, афоризм - афористика, здесь выбирать нечего.

(2) ХарАктер - характЕрный и харАктерный, возможны два фонетических варианта.

А) ХарактЕрный: здесь смещение ударения соответствует общей тенденции его перемещения к середине слова, связь с мотивирующей основой ослаблена, смысловой акцент смещен, подчеркнута ОТНЕСЕННОСТЬ к слову "характер", например, характЕрное значение. Можно заменить синонимом "свойственный".

Б) ХарАктеный: ударение остается на основе, подчеркнуто ее смысловое значение: харАктерная роль, то есть выражающая определенный характер.

Answer (score 1):

Существуют еще и особенности ударения, связанные с профессиональными жаргонами: артисты говорят - харАктерный артист, харАктерная роль, а у балетных -характЕрные танцы, характЕрная танцовщица = характЕрница